# Do we need a separate close-reason for not showing your own effort?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closing, close-reasons

One of the most prominent reasons why questions are closed is the fact that people are posting e.g. home work excercises without any additional info on where they are struck, and what they tried.

So far, these kind of questions are either closed as "This question is missing context or other details", including not showing your own work, but also sometimes as "unclear what you're asking".

Would it be a good idea to promote "You're not showing effort" as a high-level closing reason, rather than having it in the fine print.

[This older question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16499/add-an-explicit-needs-to-show-some-work-option-to-the-closing-form) was asking the same thing and I was wondering if there were any recent developments in this.

Comment: Apparently the duplicate is shown as a link when question is "closed as duplicate" but not when "marked as duplicate".

Comment: The question in question is already included in this question.

Comment: The edit history shows the usual "closed by [users] as duplicate of [link]" block.  @Roland.

Comment: It would be hard to craft perfect "boilerplate" language for this.  I understand your proposal, but showing work/effort is not the only way to add context to a Question.  Perhaps a wider consideration is whether the OP has thought at all about the meaning of a problem (I suspect some "new users" are simply posting here to get answers for a third-party), but when a Question is genuinely being posed by a user, I'm happy to hear what they see in the problem that makes it interesting.